# Javascript works fine in firefox but not in ie and chrome

Tags: javascript

http://www.measureraajje.com/

The webpage works fine in firefox and opera,
but it doesn't work at all in internet explorer, google chrome and safari.

HOW IT SHOULD WORK:
The user should select an atoll first... then the adjacent combobox should display a list of islands.

After selecting 2 islands. the user will have to press add route... then the route will be added and the result will be displayed in the table below.

Comment: he's obviously asking why it doesn't work.

Comment: The wuestion is clear, but the problem is not :/

Answer (score 0):

Use a single script tag at the end of the body tag and put in every js code which are using html elements of the page. Html elements must be present before excecuting javascript code.

Comment: i've already tried moving all the js code into the head section and calling them with the onload and onclick events. still same result, that is, the code works with firefox but not with internet explorer and chrome.

Comment: I read your js files. You need to use: '<select onchange="javascript:populateIslandFrom(this.value);">' and 'document.write ("<option value=\"" + strFilteredAtoll[arrayIndex] + "\">" + strFilteredAtoll[arrayIndex] + "</option>");'

Comment: thanks to you i've got it working on chrome... still no luck with ie... i've reconstructed few parts of the code... if u dont mind i would like u to take a look into it... thanks again